# How can the font (size, boldness, name) be changed for a python-pptx graph

Tags: report, powerpoint, python-pptx

This question is for whoever is struggling to make sense of the python-pptx docs and has not found a way to directly change the fonts ( of the x-axis, y-axis labels and etc) of their python -pptx chart objects

I will be answering my own question

Answer (score 2):

Once you've created a graph you can change its attributes as follows. I only changed the font size but you can change boldness,color, type...

```
chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data)

chart.chart_part.chart.font.size = Pt(11)
```

the .chart_part has many useful controls for python -pptx chart layout